# K8S: Pass the runAsUser permission to files created inside container

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset, security-context

Let's say I have the below yaml:

```
spec:
  securityContext:
    fsGroup: 5678
  serviceAccountName: some-account
  volumes:
    - name: secrets
      secret:
        secretName: data-secrets
    - name: secrets-sftp-passwd-key
      secret:
        secretName: sftp-passwd-key
  containers:
    - name: sftp
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1234
        runAsGroup: 5678
      image: "some/some"
      imagePullPolicy: always
      ports:
        - name: tcp-sftp
          containerPort: 22
      volumeMounts:
      - name: secrets-sftp-passwd-key
        mountPath: /etc/sftp/secret/
      - name: data
        mountPath: "/var/data"
      env:
        - name: "SFTP_USER"
          value: "some_user"
        - name: "SFTP_PASSWD"
          value: "password-1"
```

I'm trying to run the container `sftp` with `runAsUser` and `runAsGroup`. The image's entrypoint script is supposed to take the SFTP_USER, SFTP_PASSWD and create certain password and group files using this input. These files are supposed to be created in /var/data folder. After this, a proftpd process is supposed to be started using these password and group files as the 1234 user. The container starts as 1234 user. But the files have a permission of root:5678. And I get the below error:

```
unable to set UID to 0, current UID: 1234
```

The entry point script of the image is as below:

```
echo "Starting to create password file"
PASSWORD=123456
echo $PASSWORD | /usr/bin/ftpasswd --passwd --file=/var/data/ftpd.passwd --name=virtual --uid=1234 --gid=5678 --home=/var/data/ --shell=/bin/bash --stdin
echo "Password file created"
/usr/bin/ftpasswd --group --name=--group --name=virtual --file=/var/data/ftpd.group --gid=5678 --member=1234
proftpd -n  -4 -c /var/data/proftpd.conf --> This line is throwing the above error.
```

What is going wrong here? Why is it trying to set UID to 0?? I was under the impression that giving `runAsUser`, `runAsGroup` and `fsGroup` will make sure that the /var/data folder has the correct ownership of 1234.

Comment: Can you provide full yaml file that will be sufficient for reproduction? I see that you mounts data volume but I cant see where its declared. Where is the the `proftpd.conf` coming from? What`s in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're encountered is being being printed by following [code](https://github.com/proftpd/proftpd/blob/1bbb7b3e667c9f03050c692a9cecbd214bffff85/src/main.c#L2621-L2626):

```
if (geteuid() != daemon_uid) {
    pr_log_pri(PR_LOG_ERR, "unable to set UID to %s, current UID: %s",
    pr_uid2str(permanent_pool, daemon_uid),
    pr_uid2str(permanent_pool, geteuid()));
    exit(1);
}
```

You're seeing this because your container userID is not equal to the `daemon_uid`. 
If you keep looking for `daemon_uid` you will find following line:

```
uid_t *uid = (uid_t *) get_param_ptr(main_server->conf, "UserID", FALSE);
daemon_uid = (uid != NULL ? *uid : PR_ROOT_UID);
```

This means that if the `UserID` is not provided in config the code assigns`PR_ROOT_UID` value to the `daemon_uid` which appears to be 0 (root id). 
This is why the earlier mentioned if statement is generating this error message.

Take a look at the [example config](https://github.com/proftpd/proftpd/blob/1bbb7b3e667c9f03050c692a9cecbd214bffff85/sample-configurations/basic.conf#L28-L30) how to provide userID.